# Regex: match only line where numbers are located

Tags: regex, perl, numbers

Really tired of this regex. So many combinations.... I believe I need another brain :-)

Here is my problem and if someone help, I'd be highly appreciated.

I have those 6 lines of JSON response

```
...some JSON code here

    "note" : "",
    "note" : "Here is my note",
    "note" : "My note $%$",
    "note" : "Created bug 14569 in the system",
    "note" : "Another beautiful note",
    "note" : "@#$%#@%dgdeg"

...continuation of the JSON code
```

With the help of Regex, how do I match number **14569** only?

I have tried this regex, but it matches all 6 lines

```
"note"([\s\:\"a-zA-Z])*([0-9]*) - 6 matches (I only need one) 
"note"([\s\:\"a-zA-Z])*(^[0-9]*) - no matches
"note"([\s\:\"a-zA-Z])*([0-9]*+?) - pattern error
"note"([\s\:\"a-zA-Z])*(^[0-9]*+#?) - no match
```

Thanks for you help!

Updated for Matt. Below is my full JSON object

```
"response": {
        "notes": [{
    "note" : "",
    "note" : "Here is my note",
    "note" : "My note $%$",
    "note" : "Created bug 14569 in the system",
    "note" : "Another beautiful note",
    "note" : "@#$%#@%dgdeg"
        }]
    }
```

Comment: So... you have one JSON object with a bunch of duplicate keys?

Comment: @MattJacob exactly sir

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Keys must be unique in an object.

Comment: @MattJacob updated my original question

Comment: Are you sure it's not like `"notes": [{"note": ""}, {"note": ""}, ...]`? That would actually make sense.

Comment: yes exactly this is how it looks

Comment: You're saying the format is what you put in the question and also what I put in my comment above, but they're different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this regex:

```
"note"\s*:\s*".*?([0-9]++).*"
```

It will give you the number in group 1 of the match.

If you don't want to match numbers that are part of a word (e.g. "bug11") then surround the capture group with word boundary assertions (`\b`):

```
"note"\s*:\s*".*?\b([0-9]++)\b.*"
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Zf0my/3)

Comment: Thanks @Nick a lot. You saved my nerves :-)

Answer (score 1):

If all that you care about is that the line includes a number, then that is all you need to look for.

```
/[0-9]/ # matches if the string includes a digit
```

Or, as you want to capture the number:

```
/([0-9]+)/ # matches (and captures) one or more digits
```

This is a common error that I see when beginners build regular expressions. They want to build a regex that matches the whole string - when, actually, they only need to match the bit of the string that they want to match.

**Update:**

It might help to explain why some of your other attempts failed.

```
"note"([\s\:\"a-zA-Z])*([0-9]*) - 6 matches (I only need one)
```

The `*` means "match zero or more of the previous item", effectively making the item optional. This matches all lines as they all contain zero or more digits.

```
"note"([\s\:\"a-zA-Z])*(^[0-9]*) - no matches
```

The `^` means "the next item needs to be at the start of the string". You don't have digits at the start of your string.

```
"note"([\s\:\"a-zA-Z])*([0-9]*+?) - pattern error
```

Yeah. You're just adding random punctuation here, aren't you? `*+?` means nothing to the regex parser.

```
"note"([\s\:\"a-zA-Z])*(^[0-9]*+#?) - no match
```

This fails for the same reason as the previous attempt where you use `^` - the digits aren't at the start of the string. Also, the `#` has no special meaning in a regex, so `#?` means "zero or one # characters".

Answer (score 0):

If you have JSON, why don't you parse the JSON and then grep through the result?

```
use JSON 'decode_json';
my $data = decode_json( $json_text );
my @rows = map { /\b(\d+)\b/ ? $1 : () } # keep only the number
           map { $_->{note} } @$data;
```

Comment: Since the JSON has duplicate keys, this will either lose the value or die before it even gets decoded. There's no correct way to parse a JSON object like this.

Answer (score 0):

This might work  `(?m-s)^[^"\r\n]*?"note"\h*:\h*"[^"\r\n]*?\d+[^"\r\n]*".*`

https://regex101.com/r/ujDBa9/1

Explained

```
 (?m-s)                        # Multi-line, no dot-all
 ^                             # BOL
 [^"\r\n]*?                    # Not a double quote yet
 "note" \h* : \h*              # Finally, a note
 " [^"\r\n]*? \d+ [^"\r\n]* "  # Is a number embedded within the quotes ?
 .*                            # Ok, get the rest of the line
```